# Draw check and uncheck symbol on top of image in QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

How can I put check and uncheck symbol overlay on an image in QGraphicsItem? When the user clicks on the image, the check or uncheck symbol is displayed on the image. Or is there any alternative option to QGraphicsView and QgraphicsItem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The check/uncheck symbol in this case is not special - you can put overlay anything you want by adding a child item (one or more) to the item that represents the button. `QGraphicsPixmapItem` would do the job. Since it'd be a child item to the button item, its position is relative to the parent, and you can set it once and leave it unchanged - it'll always remain in the same position relative to the parent. To change between the states, store the two pixmaps somehwere "common", and set them on the pixmap item as necessary in response to the clicks on the button item.